# Supporting multiple screens in android application

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, android-fullscreen

I have a problem with supporting multiple screens with developing an android app.

Firstly, I made some layout design with the file activity_main.xml.
I never used AbsoluteLayout and only used LinearLayout. 
Plus, some layouts I used fill_parent, match_parent, wrap_content, and dp. (Probably, using dp is the problem?)

Secondly, I made folders and copied activity_main.xml file in each folder.

res/layout/activity_main.xml

res/layout-small/activity_main.xml

res/layout-large/activity_main.xml

res/layout-xlarge/activity_main.xml

res/layout-xlarge-land/activity_main.xml

Lastly, I added these codes in the manifest file.

```
<compatible-screens>
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
```

I tested it on my Samsung Galaxy Note which I bought in South Korea, the layout does not fit in entire screen.

Can anyone help me how to fix this problem?

Comment: downlaod the google io schedule app and see how they have designed layouts.

Comment: Check and post what density is your device is set to
Log.v(TAG, "density=" + getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi);

Comment: @Raghunandan Well, that does not mean that I can see the developer's code.

Comment: @user3578570 you can get the source code also and see how they designed the layouts which works on all devices

Comment: @SaqibVohra Thank you for your comment. Well, I am looking for some codes that I can fit to other devices too. Not only mine. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: @Raghunandan Oh. really? how can I see source codes?

Comment: You have to define more specifically. like: 
layout-large-hdpi,
layout-xlarge-xhdpi
you can define with more specification like
layout-sw600dp-land, layout-sw600dp-port.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, so you are saying that you dont have to be more specific about the devices you are having trouble with? I always followed this. Design a general layout and if that layout doesnt work, I specifically create a different folder for it defining its properties. If I am doing it wrong, can you please mention which approach is preferred?

Comment: I shouldn't have said completely false. What you just said in that last comment is correct. It's just that you won't ever need to mix qualifiers for sizes and qualifiers for densities. And so you won't ever need to be that precise. I'm specifically talking about your examples of layout-large-hdpi and layout-xlarge-xhdpi (your other two examples I'm ok with).

Comment: User, if you need more help, please post your xml layout. And tell us what part of the layout doesn't fit on your Note 1. Once you have enough reputation, the system will also allow you to embed screenshots of what's wrong with your layout directly in your post.

Comment: @user3578570 download from the github link and use android-studio http://code.google.com/p/iosched/wiki/Source?tm=4

Answer (score 2):

You're doing way too much here!!

You do not need to duplicate the layouts in different folders, if they're going to be the exact same ones each time.

Start over from scratch. Delete the entire compatible-screens section in your manifest.

Start with one layout with no qualifiers, and only create new layouts when you're trying to solve a particular problem (that you can't solve by tweaking that initial layout).

It seems you only tested this layout on one phone, an old Galaxy Note 1, and you haven't even tried testing it on multiple phones yet. As a rule, make it work on one screen, before you try to make it work on multiple screens.

It's ok to use dps instead of relative values such as wrap_content or fill_parent, just try to use dps in paddings, margins, and minHeight/minWidth, before trying to use them in Width and Height. And try to use gravity, or weight, or RelativeLayout, to minimize your hardcoding of too many attributes with dps.

Also, try to use nine-patches (.9.PNG) instead of straight PNGs.

Eventually, you'll want to learn to use the layout designer preview all screens functionality (the one in Android Studio, but even Eclipse now has the same functionality).

And if you want to support both tablets and phones with your layouts, definitely try to use fragments.